# Undefined symbols error when using NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, armv7

I used the NSUserDefaults in my project. But when I try to run my code I get this error message. Is it a framework that is not correctly linked?

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_userDefaults", referenced from:
      -[PlanItDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in PlanItDelegate.o
      -[PlanningViewController numberOfSectionsInTableView:] in PlanningViewController.o
      -[PlanningViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in PlanningViewController.o
      -[PlanningViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] in PlanningViewController.o
      -[PlanningViewController tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:] in PlanningViewController.o
      -[InstellingenViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in InstellingenViewController.o
      -[InstellingenViewController txtUserChanged:] in InstellingenViewController.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: `_userDefaults` is not a symbol of the `NSUserDefaults` class; thus it is not the fault of the framework. I guess, you are trying to use a global variable that is not global.

Comment: Can you post the code used to access `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: The guess of Matthias was right! I declared the global userDefaults only in the .h file. So I tried to usa a variable that was not global.

Problem solved thanks to Matthias.

@The Kraken this is my code to access NSUserDefaults

    [userDefaults setObject:txtPass.text forKey:@"password"];
    [userDefaults stringForKey:@"password"]